# #Docusign I/O error on POST request for "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token": Connection reset

Tags: docusignapi

Getting Connection reset error when making oauth call to get access token from my local server  spring application. Need yours help to fix it?. do we need any certificate required to access below api via java code? . Please guide us below is the exception

I/O error on POST request for "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token": Connection reset; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Connection reset.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a TLS negotiation issue or an idle connection in your connection pool. This post may answer your question:

[Spring Boot random "SSLException: Connection reset" in Kubernetes with JDK11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64810671/spring-boot-random-sslexception-connection-reset-in-kubernetes-with-jdk11)